# How to set top-left alignment for label text in UILabel in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel

Please anyone tell me How to set top-left,top-middle,top-left alignment for UILabel text in swift.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO @sulabh-   please share a screen shot, basically what you want to do. or code on which you are trying to work

Comment: i shared image , that is what i am expecting,in UIlabel text should start from  top-left corner..